# What is the meaning of the triangular markings in the A320 cabin?

Tags: airbus-a320, cabin

Travelling in a chartered A320 from Titan Airways. Does anyone know what these triangular markings mean? They can be seen on both sides of the cabin, a few rows before and after the emergency exits. [image]